# How does Exposed handle bind parameters?

Tags: sql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

Hello to all of you fine folks

I recently learned about [the importance of bind parameters in sql queries for optimization](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/bind-parameters).

I use kotlin-exposed in a DSL setup and when I follow the [basic query example](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DSL#read) like so:

```
TExportJobs
    .select { TExportJobs.id eq request.id.toInt() }.firstOrNull()
```

The printed query does not use bind parameters:

```
SELECT export_jobs.id, ... FROM export_jobs WHERE export_jobs.id = 4
```

Is exposed using bind paramter under the hood? Is my setup likely not formatted correctly?

Here is my example table object:

```
object TExportJobs: IntIdTable("export_jobs") {
    val userEmail = varchar("user_email", 128).index()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found it!

The sqlLogger interface (org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.SqlLogger) uses an expandArgs method from statementContext (org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.statements.StatementContext) that replaces '?' parameters.

So it is done under the hood

```
buildString {
        val quoteStack = Stack<Char>()
        var lastPos = 0
        for (i in 0..sql.length - 1) {
            val char = sql[i]
            if (char == '?') {
                if (quoteStack.isEmpty()) {
                    append(sql.substring(lastPos, i))
                    lastPos = i + 1
                    val (col, value) = iterator.next()
                    append(col.valueToString(value))
                }
                continue
            }

            if (char == '\'' || char == '\"') {
                if (quoteStack.isEmpty()) {
                    quoteStack.push(char)
                } else {
                    val currentQuote = quoteStack.peek()
                    if (currentQuote == char)
                        quoteStack.pop()
                    else
                        quoteStack.push(char)
                }
            }
        }

        if (lastPos < sql.length)
            append(sql.substring(lastPos))
    }
```